# Show that there exists a number c with a certain condition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f:[-1,1]\rightarrow\Bbb{R} $

$f(-1)=f(1)=0$, both $f$ and $f'$ are differeniable, $a\in(-1,1)$. Show that $\exists_{c\in(-1,1)}(f''(c)=\dfrac{2f(a)}{a^2-1})$.

By Lagrange's middle point theorem, we have that:

$\exists_{x_{1}\in(-1,a)}\space f'(x_1)=\dfrac{f(a)-f(-1)}{a+1}=\dfrac{f(a)}{a+1}$

$\exists_{x_{2}\in(-1,a)}\space f'(x_2)=\dfrac{f(a)-f(1)}{a-1}=\dfrac{f(a)}{a-1}$.

We know that $f'$ is differentiable so we can apply the same theorem again and obtain

$\exists_{c\in(x_1,x_2)}\space f''(c)=\dfrac{f'(x_1)-f'(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{f(a)}{a+1}-\dfrac{f(a)}{a-1}}{x_1-x_2}=\dfrac{2f(a)}{a^2-1}\dfrac{1}{x_2-x_1}$.

I thought this might be a mistake by the author and tried to find a counterexample but the thesis does seem to be correct. It's so close to the answer but I have no clue how to take it from here or if this approach is even salvageable. Why would it be so that we can always find such $x_1$ and $x_2$ that are separated by exactly $1$?

Comment: FYI, in your last line, it should be $\frac{-2f(a)}{a^2-1}\frac{1}{x_1-x_2}=\frac{2f(a)}{a^2-1}\frac{1}{x_2-x_1}$.

Comment: You are of course correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take for $A$ the constant such that the map

$$ t \mapsto g(t)= f(t) - A (t-1)(t+1)$$ vanishes at $a$, i.e. $A = \frac{f(a)}{a^2-1}$.

You have $g(-1)=g(a)=g(1)=0$. Hence it exists $c \in (-1,1)$ such that $g^{\prime \prime}(c) =0$, i.e. $f^{\prime \prime}(c) -2A=0$ and finally

$$f^{\prime \prime}(c)= \frac{2f(a)}{a^2-1}$$ as desired.